# QProcess does not complete creating file

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am just trying to create a file with QProcess by the following source code:

```
void Processmethod()
{

    QDialog *ProcessMessage = new QDialog;      
    Ui::DialogProcessMessage Dialog;            
    Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);             
    ProcessMessage->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); 
    ProcessMessage->show();

    processmethodONE(); 
} 

void processmethodONE()
{
    QString ProcessCommand = "w8 " + blablubli";            

    Prozess.setWorkingDirectory(Path);         //QProcess "Prozess" is globaly defined  
    Prozess.setStandardOutputFile(Path);       //in my class
    Prozess.start(ProcessCommand);

    QProcess::ExitStatus Status = Prozess.exitStatus(); 

    if (Status == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "File created!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This process creates out of another file which is located in the QString "Path" a new file, let me call it "PROFILE" (PRO for Problem :). The Profile also is created, but is never completed, I guess not even 50% of the file are completed.
Just when using

```
while(!Prozess.waitForFinished())
      {
       qApp->processEvents();
       std::cerr << "Process Create PROFile running " << std::endl;
      }
```

the file is written completely.
Furthermore I tried to use the QProcess finished(int) Signal to start another method and deleted the while loop (which freezes the whole GUI). I declared it in the constructor with:

```
connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, (SLOT(processmethodTWO())));
```

But I guess this could not work because the first process isn't finished completely. Where is the problem?

Comment: "great" comment dude. would be nice if you just could tell me what you mean by that? This is a forum! :P

Comment: call me pedantic and silly, but 1) giving functions a name with "function" or "method" in them is daft (although for a pure example this helps to convey your message, so just don't do it in real life code) and 2) "method" is a Java-ism. Nowhere in the C or C++ standard is that term used, and it makes me shudder to think that a Java programmer is trying to learn C++. Nothing personal `;-)`

Comment: 1) Yeah, I did that for the example, since I am no real professional programmer I just did that to make it more clear, but obviously every good programmer will see that this is a method on first view :). 2) Yeah right, I started with Java and therefore had the name "method" in mind, but when I am right I also have seen/read some german c++ tutorials where they used the name "methods" and told that "function" is more a mathematic notation (like intz = x+y). ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no warranty that right after `Prozess.start(ProcessCommand);` process will be finished, so calling "Prozess.exitStatus();" right after it will give you "false positive".  You certainly will have to wait until process is finished. You may either do it with with while loop, that you suggested or with QEventLoop

```
// ...
Prozess.setStandardOutputFile(Path);       //in my class
QEventLoop loop;
connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
Prozess.start();
loop.exec();
// Now your process status should be valid:
QProcess::ExitStatus Status = Prozess.exitStatus();
```

Comment: I tried your proposal, but including your source code the QProcess "Prozess" does not start anymore...

Comment: forgot to add Prozess.start() before loop.exec().

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than calling `waitForFinished ()`. They both block. `waitForFinished()` is the same thing.

Comment: but it makes gui processing. I can clearly see that you understand "gui blocking" in different way than me. Blocked gui doesn't response to user interaction. With QEventLoop you make your gui to work as usual

Comment: I see what you are doing now with it. I just have never see this pattern used (nested event loops in the same thread). From my understanding, its more appropriate to connect the QProcess signal to a slot that will trigger the next action, as opposed to sitting at a nested loop and waiting, unless you are going to filter out user events in that event loop and make it act like a modal dialog.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are talking about xD, but I have to say it works fine now. Thx :). I guess with QEventLoop you can create a local event loop which when used not is blocking the main event loop, right (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#details)? Could you just tell me if I will be able to kill the QProcess with the PopUp Dialogs button?

Comment: If you connect them to proper slots

Comment: @jdi Sure you can "go out" of this slot and do action in another one, but I just wanted to show the way to achieve what he wanted within one slot.