# Qt: How to connect a QPushButton of a "DialogClass1" to kill a QProcess in a "Class2"?

Tags: c++, qt, connect, signals-slots

I have the code:

```
void Processmethod()
{

    QDialog *ProcessMessage = new QDialog;      
    // HOW TO CONNECT THE DIALOGS PUSHBUTTON TO KILL THE PROCESS called in processmethodONE() ?
    Ui::DialogProcessMessage Dialog;        //polymorphy      
    Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);              
    ProcessMessage->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); 
    ProcessMessage->show();

    processmethodONE(); 
} 

void processmethodONE()
{
    QString ProcessCommand = "w8 " + blablubli";            

    Prozess.setWorkingDirectory(Path);         //QProcess "Prozess" is globaly defined  
    Prozess.setStandardOutputFile(Path);       //in my class
    QEventLoop loop;                                                                 
    connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    Prozess.start(ProcessCommand);
    loop.exec();

    QProcess::ExitStatus Status = Prozess.exitStatus(); 

    if (Status == 0)
    {
        std::cout <<"Exit-Status: " << Status << " File created!" << std::endl;
    }
else
    {
        std::cout << "Exit-Status: " << Status << " Error-Code: " << Prozess.error() << "Process failed!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to kill the QProcess "Prozess" by one of the dialogs pushButtons. The class "Ui::DialogProcessMessage" can't be edited/specified since it is the class directly constructed by the QtDesigner Ui-File and therefore will be overwritten anytime the Ui-File is edited with QtDesigner. How can I handle this? greetings

Comment: Avoid local event loops. Otherwise you're entering a world of pain. Local event loops cause all kinds of reentrancy issues (as arbitrary events can happen while its executing, e.g. someone might trigger ProcessMethod() and processMethodOne() while the loop is still executing) which are best avoided by not using local event loops.

Comment: I will have the main GUI blocked by the dialog, so nobody will trigger anything whereas the process is running, exept aborting the process will be possible. So entering a local event loop should not be a prob.:)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: The OP got the suggestion to use a local event loop from his other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956304/qprocess-does-not-complete-creating-file . I don't personally agree with that approach either. I think it should be notifying when its done via signals.

Comment: what would be the advantage? I tried to use the QProcess finished() signal with `connect(&Prozess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, (SLOT(processmethodTWO)));` to start a following method, but it does not work. Do you know whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Streight: Your connect line suggests you create Prozess on the stack. If you do that, it will be destroyed at the end of the method, i.e. right away, as there is no local event loop that blocks. Try to make the QProcess a local member variable QProcess* m_prozess.

Comment: hi again problem was solved with `connect(Dialog.pushButtonAbort, SIGNAL), &Prozess, SLOT(kill())));`. Works fine now (without creating a subclass of  Ui::DialogProcessMessage :). Probably it is, because Dialog is the "main object" in this case and the object "ProcessMessage" is just used to specify it.  I got this from the Qt Developer forum. Thx for your support anyway.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to use

```
connect(Dialog.pushButtonAbort, SIGNAL(clicked()), &Prozess, SLOT(kill()));
```

Probably it is, because Dialog is the "main object" in this case and the object "ProcessMessage" is just used to specify it. Got this from the QDeveloper forum.

THX for the support guys.

Comment: Should that SIGNAL read `SIGNAL(clicked())` ? Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

After you do this:

```
Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);
```

...`ProcessMessage` now has all of the widgets that were designed in `Ui::DialogProcessMessage`. You can access all of the items by their names.

```
connect(ProcessMessage->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```

I might be wrong about how to refer to the children, `->` or `.`, since I actually use PyQt. But I'm sure you get the idea.

Normally you would design your class from the start to inherit from the Ui class, so that all you have to do is say `setupUi(this)` in your constructor.

Currently it seems your processOne function has no reference to the dialog though so you might have to pass it in as an arg. Or connect it earlier directly to the process:

```
connect(ProcessMessage->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &Prozess, SLOT(kill()));
```

Comment: "Normally you would design your class from the start to inherit from the Ui class, so that all you have to do is say setupUi(this) in your constructor." Not really, the common pattern nowadays is to have the UI object as a member of the widget. Which follows the Composition over inheritance rule.

Comment: I tried now using your suggested connect methods after `Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);`.When using `connect(ProcessMessage->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &Prozess, SLOT(kill()));` I get the error: `Form.cpp: In member function 'int subclassGUI Processmethod() ":
Form.cpp: 5152:29: error: class QDialog has no member named 'pushButton' 
make: *** [Form.o] Error 1 ` , when using `connect(ProcessMessage->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));` I get the same error plus `Form.cpp: 5151:80: error: 'loop' was not declared in this scope` whereat this is logical to me.Any idea?

Comment: Yea you cant do literally what I typed. You need to try a little bit to apply this to your own code. What is your own QPushButton called from your UI design? I just randomly chose `pushButton`. Also, like I said you will probably have to do the second example because your QEventLoop object does not exist in the same scope as your dialog. Its basically just how you have things set up.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Where is this stated as the new common pattern?

Comment: LOL, for sure I took my own pushButtons name and not "pushButton" - I know this is just for the example. The problem is that the compiler obviously does not find my "pushButton" -> it seems he does not even search in my own Ui::DialogProcessMessage class, just in the QDialog class. Could be wrong, but that`s just how it seems to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what is different between Qt and PyQt in this situation. This approach would work fine in PyQt, where you could then access all the members directly on the QDialog after using `setupUi`

Comment: @jdi It is what one sees most in idiomatic Qt. The docs http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-using-a-ui-file.html say: "We generally recommend this approach for libraries and large applications.". Of course, the other approaches work as well.